# Costmap orientation

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I know that when using a static map in the navigation stack, the costmap origin will be overwritten by the static map. How ever changed the orientation of the static map's origin but it doesn't seem to affect the costmap's origin and I can't find a parameter to set the origin manually.
Any tip would be helpfull.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189615/costmap-orientation/) by [SouheilDehmani](https://answers.ros.org/users/11731/souheildehmani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I remember the orientation is ignored in the current code, so you might have to resort to manually rotating the gridmap in an image editor.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-11**:
Known bug: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/166

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-08-11**:
Thanks for the link!